# Perforce (p4v) - How to store same package files at different places in p4?

Tags: perforce

I am having a critical problem maintaining a single copy (same package name and same contents) of a file in Perforce, which gets used in 2 different Java projects. We have one single file used by 2 different Java projects folders; however, with the same package name and same source file. But we need to create only a single copy in Perforce. However, there is no option to do that.

Can you please let us know how do we achieve this functionality? Worst case is: we have 1 single source file as 2 separate copies in Perforce, but we want to avoid that, because that will create an inconsistency when someone checks in just that one single file in Perforce, and ignores others.

```
`enter code here`
For e.g
C:\folder1\com.aaa.ccc.FileName
C:\folder2\com.aaa.ccc.FileName
```

Comment: Can you make your build copy the source file or its class file? It is a very odd use case to ask source control to treat one file as if it were in two locations.

Comment: Add the file to the depot in it's own location. Delete the current copies (maybe Rename would be better, I think it lets you keep the history.. in this case only one copy needs be deleted). Modify the branchspecs of the projects to include this new location when integrating. (I think)

Comment: Can you use a symlink?  (works in Linux, not sure how Windows works)